# How can read / write cookie in C# & ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have problem with cookies, this is my read and write code in the class:

```
public static class language
{
   public static void set_default(string name)
   {
       HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Remove("language");
       HttpCookie language = new HttpCookie("language");
       language["name"] = name;
       language.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d);
       HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(language);
   }

   public static string get_default()
   {
       string name = string.Empty;
       HttpCookie langauge = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Get("language");
       name = langauge["name"];
       return name;
   }
}
```

When I go to the next page and use `@language.get_default()` to get the default language, the response is `null` - why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When writing cookies, you add cookies to `Response`. when Reading them you should use `Request`:

```
HttpCookie language = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("language");
```

So the `set_default()` is correct, but you should make change to `get_default()`

Answer (score 6):

am not sure `language.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d);` is correct. **DateTime.Now.AddDays** accepts an integer and **1d** is not.

CREATE COOKIE:

```
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("language", "ENGLISH", new CookieOptions()
            {
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5)
            });
```

GET COOKIE:

```
 string language = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["language"];
```

DELETE COOKIE:

```
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("language", "", new CookieOptions()
            {
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
            });
```

or

```
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete("language");
```