# Trying to implement a Cookie and Session page visit counter in my controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, cookies, model-view-controller

Sorry I'm a new programmer so I don't really know what I'm doing, I tried something like this.

```
public IActionResult List(int count)
        {
            count++;
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("counter", count.ToString());
            Response.Cookies.Append("counter", count.ToString());
            var albums = _albumsDbContext.Albums.Include(a => a.Studio).OrderByDescending(a => a.YearProduced).ToList();
            return View(albums);
        }
```

But the count obviously just stayed at 1 no matter how many times I visited the page, could you guys link me to some documentation or tell me what i'm doing wrong to accomplish my goal?

Comment: Why do you need to count the number of times a user visits a page? Using a Cookie may not be the solution since it will only be linked to a user browser.

Comment: That is what I was assigned to do, haha.

Comment: Be sure this is what you really want, a cookie would count the number of times a user visited the page with the same browser (if he did not clear the cookies) and will oviously be stored on user side. That being said, I guess the argument `count` is supposed to be an HTTP GET parameter. What you want is read the old `count` value from the cookie.

Comment: Its what I really want, "What you want is read the old count value from the cookie." How do I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51577811/how-can-read-write-cookie-in-c-sharp-asp-net-mvc . You should also check if the cookie exists after trying to retrieve it.